# Sum of Normalized Rademacher Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_{n}$ for $n\ge 1$ be i.i.d. Rademacher ($\pm 1$) random variables.  For what $p$ does
$$\frac{1}{n^{p}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$$

converge almost surely and for what $p$ does it diverge almost surely?  It follows from the $3$-series theorem and Kronecker's lemma that for $p > \frac{1}{2}$, it converges almost surely to $0$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ in place of $\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k$?

Comment: @bangs I very much did.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The law of the iterated logarithm states that
\begin{align}
\limsup_n\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}\log\log n}\to1 \text{ a.s.},\\
\liminf_n\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}\log\log n}\to-1 \text{ a.s.},
\end{align}
where $S_n=\sum_1^nX_k$. In words, for each $\omega$ in a set of probability 1, the sample path $S_n(\omega)/(\sqrt{n}\log\log n)$ is arbitrary close to $1$ infinitely often and to $-1$ i.o. as $n\to\infty$. Therefore, $n^\epsilon\log\log n\to\infty$ for $\epsilon\ge 0$ implies that
\begin{align}
\limsup_n (n^\epsilon\log\log n) S_n(\omega)/(\sqrt{n}\log\log n)=\limsup_nS_n(\omega)/n^{1/2-\epsilon}=\infty\\
\liminf_n (n^\epsilon\log\log n) S_n(\omega)/(\sqrt{n}\log\log n)=\liminf_n S_n(\omega)/n^{1/2-\epsilon}=-\infty.
\end{align}
So for $p\le 1/2$ the process fails to converge almost surely.

Comment: For the case $p < 1/2$, you are saying that I should take $\lim n^{\varepsilon} = \infty$ in Slutsky's theorem?  Is the argument that if $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ (in distr.) then $n^{\varepsilon}X_{n}\rightarrow 0$ (in distr.), and this implies that the limit doesn't exist?  Also, the case $p=1/2$ was the case that I was most interested in.  Does this argument not apply to that case?

Comment: For your first question, yes. For other questions, I fixed 2 typos in my answer; does that make it clearer?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately, I do not see from your argument whether the sum converges almost surely in the case that $p=1/2$.  I don't think that converging in distribution to a Gaussian implies almost sure convergence.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user3281410 My mistake, I missed that you were looking for a.s. convergence. I will update for $p=1/2$ probably using law of the iterated logarithm.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.  I will check all the details and accept the answer if everything works!

Comment: This works great.  If I am understanding correctly, you did mean to write $\sqrt{2n\log(\log(n))}$ instead of $\sqrt{n}\log(\log(n))$ though, right?

Comment: @user3281410 You're right, thanks for catching that typo (and the more serious errors in my first response). I will clean it up at some point.